# Can PowerShell run/handle multiple scripts at once using the IE COM Object?

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, scripting, com

I have a handful of PowerShell scripts which use the IE COM Object to open Internet Explorer and log into a web site and download a number of PDF files.

I would like these scripts to run on a production server and furthermore am wondering if its possible for them all to run at once, side by side without interruption. Or on the other hand, if they indeed must be kicked off sequentially, one by one.

Anyone have experience with this?

This is how I am calling the scripts, and it appears to me as though COM can only handle one at a time, regardless if they are in separate processes

```
Start-Process PowerShell "S:\pathtoscript1.ps1"
Start-Process PowerShell "S:\pathtoscript2.ps1"
Start-Process PowerShell "S:\pathtoscript3.ps1"
```

Comment: you might wanna have a look at Invoke-WebRequest

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

Each com-object launch their own `iexplore.exe` process so it should work AFAIK.

Comment: Hmm I don't believe I've tried that. How is that done?

Comment: You say you have multiple scripts.... Run them in multiple powershell-processes...  `powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -file c:\script1.ps1`  etc..

Comment: Shouldn't they run in multiple processes by default? I think they already do

Comment: So, yes..I am already running them as separate processes. But yet it seems like there is still some interference when they run. As though IE COM can only work with one at a time.

Comment: That depends on how you run them. I don't know how you do it.. You didn't say in your question. You didn't say it didn't work, you didn't say that you tried......

Comment: I just executed to scripts at the same time which used ie com-object and opened their own visible window at different websites.. Worked just fine. Tested a script like yours with `Start-Process`... Still no problem.

Comment: The windows open fine for me as well. Its the PDF downloading I am concerned with. I ran 3 scripts at once and they did not all complete as should. This is why I am wondering if its even possible to run all together or if I'm better off kicking them one by one

Comment: Then add a sample script that actually works. We can't help if I can't reproduce it. If you don't need to login etc., then try using `Invoke-WebRequest` to download the files.